# Include js to rotate image vs keeping 9 different images?

Tags: jquery, html, css, seo, pagespeed

I have to implement one meter as shown below:
[image]

Now I have move the needle to 9 different positions according to the percentage (10-90%)

I can implement this using two different ways:

```
1- jQuery rotate js, in which I have to include one js file in my page.
2- I have to keep 9 different images of needle and use them according to my need.
```

So I want to know which approach is better keeping optimization of page for google page speed in mind?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think number 1 is faster, because the browser won't need to cache 9 different images.

To rotate de needle you could use `transform: rotate(Xdeg);` .

[Transform docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#rotate)

Comment: But it will not work in  IE9, IE7 & IE8. Well I have to show these images on some event. At first load of page it will not be there.

Comment: You can use `transform` on IE9+.

Comment: true but what about IE8 and IE7

Comment: If the older versions are so important, I think the only option is to use the 9 images then. Even using some jQuery plugin it will be a little buggy in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transform: rotate(xdeg);` and if you're looking to support both IE7 & IE8 you need to include a `Matrix Transform`:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(
  M11 = COS_THETA,
  M12 = -SIN_THETA,
  M21 = SIN_THETA,
  M22 = COS_THETA,
  sizingMethod = 'auto expand'
);
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(
  M11 = COS_THETA,
  M12 = -SIN_THETA,
  M21 = SIN_THETA,
  M22 = COS_THETA,
  SizingMethod = 'auto expand'
)";
```

You can check out this site for the matrices calculation: http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/transforms/matrix-calculator.html

Here's a jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2Yz6w/

But I also think that 9 needle images isn't that much of an impact on page load time.